# How to rotate WCF log when maxMessagesToLog is reached?

Tags: wcf, logging

I have a WCF service and want to enable logging. As described in Microsoft's documentation [Configuring Message Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/configuring-message-logging#feedback), I put in the Web.config the following:

```
<system.diagnostics>  
  <sources>  
    <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">  
      <listeners>  
         <add name="messages"  
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"  
              initializeData="c:\logs\messages.svclog" />  
        </listeners>  
    </source>  
  </sources>  
</system.diagnostics>  

<system.serviceModel>  
  <diagnostics>  
    <messageLogging   
         logEntireMessage="true"   
         logMalformedMessages="false"  
         logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"   
         logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"  
         maxMessagesToLog="3000"  
         maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>  
  </diagnostics>  
</system.serviceModel>
```

How can I rotate the log, for example write to messages1.svclog, then messages2.svclog, etc. when the number of messages in the last log has reached maxMessagesToLog=3000?

I read the article [A Rolling XmlWriterTraceListener](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30956/A-Rolling-XmlWriterTraceListener), but this rotates the log file when a certain file size has been reached. However, when the number of messages reaches maxMessagesToLog, WCF will stop logging.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.Net WCF Service Trace Log with log file management (Rolling)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779812/net-wcf-service-trace-log-with-log-file-management-rolling).  Though there is a link there that points to the same article above, there are some other useful tips.  You could make your own as mentioned, or as the other answer says, roll a new log each day.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to find out how to rotate the log file before maxMessagesToLog is reached.

I decided to rotate the log file every midnight. Setting maxMessagesToLog to max integer = 2147483647, the number of messages in one day will never exceed that value.
I used the custom trace listener as described in the [WCF Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/85198f78-26e1-4681-baf5-d3281a8264c1/wcf-rotating-message-log-file?forum=wcf).

```
public class CustomTraceListener : XmlWriterTraceListener
{
    public CustomTraceListener(string fileName)
        : base(string.Format(fileName,
                  string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Year)))
    {
    }
}

<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
      <listeners>
        <add name="traceListener"
            type="MyService.CustomTraceListener, MyService"
            initializeData= "c:\wcflogs\messages_{0}.svclog" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

I created my application pool with Recycling Specific Times = 00:00:00

```
appcmd add apppool /name:MyApppool/enable32BitAppOnWin64:true /+recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.[value='00:00:00']
```

The advanced settings of the application pool look with this command as follows:

[image]

Therefore, the process is recycled every midnight, and the messages counter starts from 0. As long as I have less then 2 billion messages per day, I will have all messages in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use symbolic links.  You can delete and reset symbolic link while IIS is running.  Then when it recycles or restarts a new file will be created.

for example you can create a symbolic link with a command like this:

```
mklink server_tracelog.svclog server_tracelog_1.svclog
```

You then set in the web.config this file 'server_tracelog.svclog', but this will be the real file it writes to 'server_tracelog_1.svclog'

Then maybe using a schedule task you could run a batch file that has something like this:

```
REM set day of week as %DAYOFWEEK%
for /f %%a in ('wmic path win32_localtime get DAYOFWEEK /format:list ^| findstr "="') do (set %%a)

del server_tracelog.svclog
del server_tracelog_dayofweek_%DAYOFWEEK%.svclog
mklink server_tracelog.svclog server_tracelog_dayofweek_%DAYOFWEEK%.svclog
```

Then if your app pool recycles once a day, you will have a new log created each day.